# How can I make my regex /^\966[\d]{9}$/ or jquery function work on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Using jQuery I am validating field with regex `/^\966[\d]{9}$/` that allows only digits, 9 digit limit with 966 prefix. It is working perfectly on Windows, Android and iPhone as well. However when I test it on iPad it is not working.

I have searched but could not find the solution.

```js
var regexMobileEnquiry = /^\966[\d]{9}$/

ValidateRegex($("#lblReporterMobile"), $("#txtReporterMobile"), regexMobileEnquiry)

function ValidateRegex(lbl, txt, regex) {
  var re = regex;
  if (!txt.val().trim().match(re)) {
    lbl.addClass("error");
    return false;
  } else {
    lbl.removeClass("error");
    return true;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="lblReporterMobile" class="control-label">Reporter Mobile </label>
<input name="txtReporterMobile" type="text" id="txtReporterMobile" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" maxlength="15">
```

Comment: The regex itself isn't the issue. It's more likely to be *how* you're applying the regex, or the event handler it's placed in to. That's the code we need to see in order to diagnose the issue

Comment: I have updated my question @RoryMcCrossan

Comment: The regex is not correct as you escape a word (digit) char. Use `/^966\d{9}$/`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks your regex is working fine on iPad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you are using contains `\9` which can be interpreted as a backreference to a ninth capturing group. Most JS `RegExp` implementations can handle this situation, but it seems it is not the case in iPad.

I suggest "normalizing" the pattern as

```
/^966\d{9}$/
```

It means

- Remove `\` before `9` to remove any ambiguity related to escaped number patterns
- Turn `[\d]` into `\d` as it makes no sense to create a character class out of a single shorthand character class.

Comment: Although yours is more accurately written, but since `[\d]` is similar to `\d` here, then this doesn't, mean that the regex written by @Sami is incorrect.

Comment: @Code_Ninja No, `[\d]` does not mean to do the job, it is more stylistic. The problem is with `\9` parsing. Note that OP [confirmed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54826065/how-can-i-make-my-regex-966-d9-or-jquery-function-work-on-ipad/54827610?noredirect=1#comment96429626_54826065) the fixed regex works. My regex is not "more accurately written", it is free from ambiguity and is the solution to the current problem.

Comment: But for someone who is new at regex, the `[\d]` syntax also works. Its good what you have mentioned here, but its just that, this is not an answer, this should be a comment.

Comment: @Code_Ninja If you re-read the answer you will see that `[\d]` is not the point at all. It is actually a *comment* in my *answer*.

Comment: Its about normalizing, got it. Thanks.